# Strongly asymmetric graphs

Tags: graph-theory

[Asymmetric graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_graph) are graphs that have a trivial automorphism group $\textrm{Aut}(G)$, i.e. the only graph isomorphism from $G$ to itself is the identity.

Let's call a graph $G$ strongly asymmetric if the only graph *homomorphism* $h: G\to G$ is the identity (in other words, the endomorphism monoid $\textrm{End}(G)$ is trivial).

Given a (finite or infinite) cardinal $\kappa > 0$, is there a strongly asymmetric graph on $\kappa$ vertices?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1037885/graph-with-only-the-identity-as-endomorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the common name for such graphs is *rigid*. In fact, most random graphs are rigid. See this reference: [On the minimal order of a graphs within a semigroup](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895684900212).

Comment: A cautionary note: in many contexts, "rigid" is taken to mean merely "no nontrivial automorphisms" e.g. here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9411236v1.pdf

Comment: That's right -- I think the reference given in the answer above might refer to existence of a trivial *auto* (but not endo) morphism only... I'm not sure we already have an answer for the question whether for any cardinal there is a rigid graph (in the strong sense).